# Where to put tests testing the configuration in the YAML files

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, sonata, phpunit

I'm developing an application in Symfony (version 4.2.3) and use also few bundles from the [Sonata](https://sonata-project.org) project as well the [API Platform](https://api-platform.com).
We have 4 different user roles with different privilegies. The API is read-only and should be accessed by `ROLE_USER`, but `ROLE_USER` must not access the admin area. The other roles should access the admin area.

I have set up the firewalls and access control paths in the file `config/packages/security.yaml`, created my custom security handler `VoterSecurityHandler` and use it in `config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml`:

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.voter
```

The security handler is registered in `config/services.yaml`:

```
sonata.admin.security.handler.voter:
    class: App\Security\Handler\VoterSecurityHandler
    arguments: ["@security.authorization_checker", ['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']]
```

I wrote tests using [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/tree/master) and supplying data fixtures with different users to check if their permissions are properly handled.

I'm trying to follow best practices and map the whole application structure from `src/` into the directory `tests/`. Since I have `src/Security/Handler/VoterSecurityHandler.php` I created `tests/Security/Handler/TestVoterSecurityHandler.php`.

However the `VoterSecurityHandler` should manage the permissions for the sonata admin, and I'm actually testing the configuration settings in `config/packages/security.yaml`.

It doesn't feel right to place all the tests in the above mentioned class, but I'm wondering where should I put this kind of "smoke tests"?

**My question:**
Where do I put tests testing the configuration in the YAML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good practice is to put the test files under the same architecture than your src, but it does not mean you can't write other test files.
If you have no controller, put it directly under tests, and name it how you want (`FirewallTest`?)

I personally use a dedicated functional test which  tests different routes for different roles and only check if I get a 403 / 200.

As you can see here in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/tests.html#functional-tests) they put their file directly under tests : `tests/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest.php`

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer, do you have `SecurityController`? Because I have no controllers at all in my application. The API endpoints are defined with annotations and for the admin area I have the admin classes. Otherwise it's a good idea.

Comment: The good practice is to put the test files under the same architecture than your src, but it does not mean you can't write other test files. If you have no controller, put it directly under tests, and name it how you want (`FirewallTest`?)

Comment: Thank you for the last comment. It is much better than your answer, because it actually answers the question. If you edit your answer outlining this, I'll upvote it and accept it (if there are no better answers in the meantime).

Comment: Directly under `src/` there is a file `Kernel.php`, which is generated automatically when bootstrapping a Symfony project. It reads all the settings under `packages`. So now I'm tempted to put my tests in `KernelTest.php`.

Comment: No it would mean than you are testing the kernel. Updating my answer

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. I think that sums it well up.